# How to get specific field of an associative array without using a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to get a specific field of an array but it keeps on sending me error like `Undefined index: in` or `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`.I'm using codeigniter and this array is from my model and it is returned in my controller. Here is my controller.

```
  $data['inpatient'] = $this->billing_model->retrieveinpatient();
  echo $data['inpatient']['in'];
```

Here is the structure of my array:

```
 Array
 (
  [inpatient] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [iid] => 1
                [in] => IN
            )
    )

)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access an object with the array dot notation.

Try this:

```
echo $data['inpatient'][0]->in;
```

The `$data['inpatient']` is indeed an array, so you can use the index notation. In my example, the index is `0`. Once you're pointing to the correct index, you'll have a `stdClass Object` to work with. In order to extract a property of `stdClass Object`, you can use the object property notation `->` to get at the `in` property.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your structure. The array output is key => value. Your first array has key `inpatient`. The `inpatient` value is an array with one key - 0, holding stdClass.

So it must be

```
echo $data['inpatient'][0]->in;
```

Comment: it returns `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in `